# update a grid form another thread vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I try to update the grid vaadin from another thread but a new data have shown only when I ping some component on UI.

I want to display data in the grid when a thread get a result from bd

```
  CURRENT = UI.getCurrent();
        taskSlaService.getFilterAsync(pointId, dictValueIds)
                .thenAcceptAsync(entities -> {

                    log.info("entities {}", entities);

                    if (entities.isEmpty()) {
                        log.info("entities is empty =====> {}", entities);
                    }

                    if (CURRENT != null) {
                        CURRENT.access(() -> {
                            log.info("========> UI isn't null");
                            grid.setItems(entities);
                            grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
                            log.info("entities in UI.getCurrent().access =====> {}", entities);
                            log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            CURRENT.getPage().reload();
                        });
```

Comment: You need to enable server push, so the server can send updates to the ui, even when no usr interaction is done

Comment: Unrelated remark: There's probably no need to do `refreshAll` after `setItems` since the component is already refreshing all items based on the first call. Reloading the page after all of that is also redundant, but I assume that's just a relic of you debugging attempts.

Comment: Thanks, Andre! @Push annotation helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enable push:

```
@Push
public class Application implements AppShellConfigurator {
  ...
}
```

Read more about push here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/server-push